# Weird line in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using the appearance proxy to set the UIBarButtonItem's background image:

```
UIImage *buttonBBI = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bbi_texture.png"]
                       resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 4, 5, 4)];
```

This is `bbi_texture@2x.png` (retina)
[image]

But there's a white bar that appears in the button. Any idea what might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: If you move the button vertically (before displaying it), what happens to the white line? That will indicate whether the problem is in the button itself or another view.

Comment: Could it be something about the style of the button? You might also use a tool like [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/) to see if there's an extra view on top of your button or look at the resulting images?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below will work fine

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:@selector(goHome:)];

 NSArray *leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeButton,nil];

self.yourViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftBarButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make custom UIBarButton. Works perfect for me.

```
UIButton *postView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 61, 30)];
[postView setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postView addTarget:self action:@selector(showAddPost) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[postView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bbi_texture.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bbi_texture.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIBarButtonItem *postButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:postView];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:postButton];
```